# Error en petición SOAP al WebService SRI-ECUADOR

Tags: php, laravel, json, soap

Tengo el siguiente controlador que realiza la petición soap hacia el SRI-Ecuador.

```
    try {
        $infoFactura = InvoiceManager::generarFactura($request);
        $firma = InvoiceManager::firmarDocumento($infoFactura['ruta'],$infoFactura['nombre'],$infoFactura['documento']);
        $sri = "";
        $data = [];
        if ($firma['data']!=false) {
            $sri = "paso validacion de firma";
            $sri = InvoiceManager::conexionSRI($firma['data']);
            $data = [
                'completo' => $sri,
                'estado' => $sri->RespuestaRecepcionComprobante->estado, // "RECIBIDA" | "DEVUELTA"
                'clave_acceso' => $sri->RespuestaRecepcionComprobante->comprobantes->comprobante->claveAcceso,
                // ->mensajes (podrian ser mas de 1)
                'mensaje' => $sri->RespuestaRecepcionComprobante->comprobantes->comprobante->mensajes->mensaje->mensaje,
                'tipo' => $sri->RespuestaRecepcionComprobante->comprobantes->comprobante->mensajes->mensaje->tipo, // "ERROR"
            ];
             if ($sri->RespuestaRecepcionComprobante->estado=="DEVUELTA") {
                 InvoiceManager::eliminarFactura($infoFactura['documento']);
             }
        } else {
            // error al firmar el documento
            InvoiceManager::eliminarFactura($infoFactura['documento']);
        }
        return response()->json(['meta'=>['code'=>$firma['estatus']],'data'=>$firma['data'],'sri'=>$data],$firma['estatus']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['meta'=>['code'=>500],'data'=>$e->getMessage()],500);
    }
```

Conexión al SRI:

```
public static function conexionSRI($doc)
{
    try {
        if (env('APP_ENV')=='local') {
            self::setWsdl("https://celcer.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantesOffline?wsdl");
        } else {
            self::setWsdl("https://cel.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantesOffline?wsdl");
        }
        self::$service = InstanceSoapClient::init();

        $decodeContent = base64_encode(file_get_contents($doc->signed_xml));
        //$xml = StAlDocs::envoltura($decodeContent);
        $xml =
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ec='http://ec.gob.sri.ws.recepcion'>".
                "<soapenv:Header/>".
                "<soapenv:Body>".
                    "<ec:validarComprobante>".
                        "<!--Optional:-->".
                        "<xml>".$decodeContent."</xml>".
                    "</ec:validarComprobante>".
                "</soapenv:Body>".
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";

        $param = array(
            'xml' => $xml
        );

        $consulta = self::$service->validarComprobante($param);
        return $consulta;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

Al parecer todo esta funcionando bien, pero me retorna el siguiente error de respuesta "ARCHIVO NO CUMPLE ESTRUCTURA XML" y al verlo mas a fondo exactamente el problema es con la variable claveAcceso, que ni bien no me la esta tomando o quizás no me la este devolviendo el Sri, no estoy muy seguro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al generar el Documento XML si esta presente la etiqueta o tag que en este caso esta requiriendo `<ClaveAcceso></ClaveAcceso>`, pero no he logrado dar con el problema.

Comment: Es fácil, ese error te lo devuelve cuando adicionas casillas para datos personas y lo dejas vacío, por eso no cumple estructura XML. En mi caso que uso la Herramienta del SRI, AL colocar datos adicionales de la factura dejo una casilla en blanco, para que no genere ese error le pongo un espacio o un punto para q no se encuentre vacio y cumpla estructura.

Comment: Esto va más de la documentación que provea quien mantiene el web service.